# Getting information from the Bearer Token in .net core api to do additional authorization on an endpoint

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I have an angular client that authorizes users via Auth0 and then uses the token from Auth0 to consume an API that is built in .net core.  The authentication in Startup.cs is

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "removed";
                options.Audience = "removed";
            });
```

I have an endpoint like this

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("preview/{questionId}")]
[...]
public ActionResult<Question> GetQuestionPreviewById(string questionId)
{
  ...
  return Ok(model);
}
```

This all works fine.  However, I would like to put additional authorization logic on this endpoint and that would require knowing who the user is - that information is available on the token (the `sub` field) but I:
1. Don't know how to get to that from the endpoint
2. Don't *think* the endpoint is the correct place to do this.

My gut tells me I should have another (in angular language) guard that can be added to the endpoint, something like

```
[Authorize]
[AuthorizeOwnershipOfRequestedObject]
```

But I don't know how to do this in .net.

How do I go about using the provided token to add additional authorization on an endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

1) you need first to assign claims to a specific user

2) In configure services add authorization with option to include policies

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
    options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy => 
      policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber"));
   });
}
```

3) You then apply the policy using the Policy property on the AuthorizeAttribute attribute to specify the policy name

```
[Authorize(Policy = "EmployeeOnly")]
public IActionResult VacationBalance()
{
   return View();
}
```